# Python sock.recv not getting all data from page

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

this has been very hard step for me learning how to do low level socket communication but I really want to learn this, I've come to a wall and I don't seem to be able to find the proper WAY.

How am I able to get all the data ? I've tried multiple things I'm just able to get partial of the response.

the URL I'm trying right now is:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=asc&appid=730&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Rarity%5B%5D=tag_Rarity_Ancient_Weapon
```

After research I tried this way but still wasn't able to print the full JSON page above, anything I'm doing wrong ?

```
        sock.send(request)
        response = ""
        first = True
        length = 0
        while True:
            partialResponse = sock.recv(65536)
            if len(partialResponse) != 0:
                #print("all %s" % partialResponse)
                # Extract content length from the first chunk
                if first:
                    startPosition = partialResponse.find("Content-Length")
                    if startPosition != -1:
                        endPosition = partialResponse.find("\r\n", startPosition+1)
                        length = int(partialResponse[startPosition:endPosition].split(" ")[1])
                    first = False
                # add current chunk to entire content
                response += partialResponse
                # remove chunksize from chunck
                startPosition = response.find("\n0000")
                if startPosition != -1:
                    endPosition = response.find("\n", startPosition+1)
                    response = response[0:startPosition-1] + response[endPosition+1:]
                if len(response[response.find("\r\n\r\n")+2:]) > length:
                    break
            else:
                break
        print response
```

Comment: If you want the whole thing, why are you asking for a max of 64K bytes?

Comment: what is the max I should ask for ?

Comment: @ryachza well i've tried printing response to a log and each time, the response is cut short compared to what shows on chrome browser.

Comment: Meh.  Brainfart on my part -- thinking about file reads :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to duplicate the issue and it seemed that the server was not returning a content-length header, causing the `if len(response[..]) > length` to trigger with length 0. Changing that statement to `if length > 0 and ...` seemed to resolve it.

I had to increase the time out I had set from .3 to .5 seconds in order to consistently get responses.

I was receiving a content-length in Chrome, but probably because the content-encoding was gzip. I guess they don't send a content-length for uncompressed responses.

The Content-Length section of [this document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) lists the header as a "SHOULD".

Other general recommendation: I would not assume that the first chunk will always include all headers. There really should be no switch on "first". You should probably read until you encounter the `\r\n\r\n` that signals the header completion and process that separately with everything following being the response body.

**Edit per comment:**

For something quick and dirty, I would probably just do this:

```
response = ''
while True:
    chunk = sock.recv(65536)

    if len(chunk) == 0:
      break
    else:
      response += chunk

pieces = response.split('\r\n\r\n')

headers = pieces[0]
body = '\r\n\r\n'.join(pieces[1:])

print response
print body
print headers

print len(response), len(body), len(headers)
```

Just rip everything the socket receives into a string and don't try to interpret it at all. This will give you the best chance of getting everything.

I definitely think playing around at this level is a great way to learn and completely worth every moment of the time. That being said, there is a reason libraries are commonly preferred for this sort of thing.

There really isn't a whole lot *guaranteed* by HTTP - it's very flexible and there are a lot of variables. So you will need to start with essentially no expectations/requirements, and carefully build up constantly thinking about "what if this/that". One thing to be careful of is that the chunking can happen *anywhere*. A chunk could break before the headers complete, it could even break say in between an `\r` and `\n` meaning you would need to parse across chunks to detect boundaries. For common usage, reading the whole response into memory probably isn't a problem, but of course it's possible for certain responses or other requirements to make that impractical/impossible.

Comment: Is there an easier way, or more efficient way of receiving all the page without all the conditions I wrote above ? It somewhat feels like too much work.